# Extjs4 TabBar of Tabpanel with multiple rows?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, tabpanel

Users do not like the scrolling tabs in the tabpanel. Is there any solution to order tabs in multiple rows?

```
var tp = Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
    anchor: '100%',
    border: 0,
    items: [form, grid /*, ... */]
    tabBar: {
        // ???
    }
});
```

Comment: There has been a discussion on this topic on Sencha forum. https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?26464-Suggestion-Multi-row-tab-bar

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible in ExtJS4.

You can either write your own CSS for tabpanel or a custom extension, which will do the trick.